# Checking next openingHours in array with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array representing buinessTimes of a restaurant, knowing the current index of the current day, lets say 5, representing saturday and the next opening day being monday, I want to show the next time the venue will open.

I'm using a for loop to check this but the problem is the loop ends and I don't know how to go back to the start of the array...

```
const [openingTimes, setOpeningTimes] = useState([
        {day:'lunes', hours:    [ { opens: '09:00', closes: '17:30' }, { opens: '21:00', closes: '03:00' } ]},
        {day:'martes', hours:    [ { opens: '09:00', closes: '17:30' }, { opens: '21:00', closes: '03:00' } ]},
        {day:'miércoles', hours:    [ { opens: '09:00', closes: '17:30' }, { opens: '21:00', closes: '03:00' } ]},
        {day:'jueves', hours:    [ { opens: '09:00', closes: '17:30' }, { opens: '21:00', closes: '03:00' } ]},
        {day:'viernes', hours:    [ { opens: '09:00', closes: '17:30' }, { opens: '21:00', closes: '03:00' } ]},
        {day:'sabado', hours:    [ { opens: '09:00', closes: '17:30' }, { opens: '21:00', closes: '03:00' } ]},
        {day:'domingo', hours:    [ ]},
    ]);

const currentDayIndex = 5;
let foundNextOpeningDay = false;

for(var i=0; i<openingTimes.length; i++)
{
                if(i > weekdayIndex && openingTimes[i].hours.length > 0 && !foundNextOpeningDay)
                {
                    let willOpenNext = openingTimes[i].hours[0].opens;
                }
}
```

Comment: Check if the current index is the lastenderes if, take index 0. if the index is the index of the array, you don’t even need a loop. Just increase the index, except for the last one.

Comment: Why are you looping if you know the index you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to know the next working hours, use `(i+ 1) % 7` to calculate the next day.

and your question may not be clear enough. sunday also has work hours ,why is Saturday's next day mondy?

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically know that sunday will always be closed, then you can just use:

```js
var nextDay = (currentDayIndex + 1)%6;
var willOpenNext = openingTimes[nextDay].hours[0].opens;
```

As for why your loop doesn't work, I can see a couple problems:

1. Using `let`. In javascript, `var` is scoped within a function (as in, once you leave a function the variable does not exist), but `let` and `const` are scoped within the *block*. This means that within your loop, because you used `let`, that you set `willOpenNext` inside an if, and then immediately leave, destroying that variable. You need to use `var` instead, OR pre-define the variable outside the loop.
2. You never actually change `foundNextOpeningDay`.  I can see you are trying to include a check to stop the loop once you have the variable, but you don't actually have a line that sets `foundNextOpeningDay = true`. May I suggest that an easier way to achieve the same thing, is get rid of the check and just use a `break` once you find the variable?
3. If the current day is 5, then your first check doesn't work.

Edit: If Sunday could also possibly have hours, then we can still just use a simple for loop:

```js
for (let i = (currentDayIndex + 1)%7; i !== currentDayIndex; i = (i + 1)%7) {
  if (openingTimes[i].hours.length) {
    var willOpenNext = openingTimes[i].hours[0].opens;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: For `nextDay` calculation you should be using `%7` not `%6` as `var nextDay = (currentDayIndex + 1)%7;`. Because with `%6` it will produce result between 0-5 but for week it is also required to include 6.

Comment: No it is not required. As I said at the start, if we know for sure that Sunday (ie. index 6) is closed, then we don't need to include it, therefore `%6` saves us the effort of checking if the next day is sunday.

Answer (score 0):

Use `while` loop instead of `for` as explained below.

1. You should be using `%7` with finding next index so it will produce index between `0-6`.
2. Once you found opening day set foundNextOpeningDay = true, so loop can end.
3. Declare willOpenNext variable outside `while` block so it will be accessible to entire function.
4. Increment nextDayIndex to check for next day if opening day not found.

Try it below.

```js
const openingTimes = [
        {day:'lunes', hours:    [ { opens: '09:00', closes: '17:30' }, { opens: '21:00', closes: '03:00' } ]},
        {day:'martes', hours:    [ { opens: '09:00', closes: '17:30' }, { opens: '21:00', closes: '03:00' } ]},
        {day:'miércoles', hours:    [ { opens: '09:00', closes: '17:30' }, { opens: '21:00', closes: '03:00' } ]},
        {day:'jueves', hours:    [ { opens: '09:00', closes: '17:30' }, { opens: '21:00', closes: '03:00' } ]},
        {day:'viernes', hours:    [ { opens: '09:00', closes: '17:30' }, { opens: '21:00', closes: '03:00' } ]},
        {day:'sabado', hours:    [ { opens: '09:00', closes: '17:30' }, { opens: '21:00', closes: '03:00' } ]},
        {day:'domingo', hours:    [ ]},
    ];
    
const currentDayIndex = 5;
// set next day index with % 7 so index will range between 0-6
let nextDayIndex = (currentDayIndex + 1) % 7;
// initialize flag as false
let foundNextOpeningDay = false;
// declare variable outside while block so it will be accessible to entire function
let willOpenNext = "";

while (!foundNextOpeningDay) {
  // check for next opening times
  if (openingTimes[nextDayIndex].hours.length > 0) {
    // if opening times found then set foundNextOpeningDay to true so loop will end
    foundNextOpeningDay = true;
    // set opening day value to willOpenNext object
    willOpenNext = "Day : " + openingTimes[nextDayIndex].day + ", hours : " + openingTimes[nextDayIndex].hours[0].opens;
  }
  
  // increment nextDayIndex to check for next day if opening day not found
  nextDayIndex = (nextDayIndex + 1) % 7;
}

console.log(willOpenNext);
```